# Showing output of the Eclipse launching console in Eclipse itself

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am launching Eclipse from the command line to be able to see the output generated by certain plugins (the reason I need to see the output in this way is that it is generated by JNI based libraries, and I have not found any other way to see such output).

However, I am wondering if I could visualize the output shown at the launching console, inside Eclipse itself. Does someone know if such a thing is possible ?

Comment: Can't you put the output in a file and view that in?

Comment: I think so, but that would mean that the file needs to be refreshed every time I want to check it, isnt it?. I was thinking more in visualizing something in Eclipse that behaves like a console showing output every time certain actions occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no general way to do this in eclipse..  The eclipse console shows the stdin/stdout/stderr streams of processes launched from within eclipse.  The JNI output is available easily to the process that **launches** eclipse, but not eclipse itself.

PW

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal but if you load the PDE plugins into your eclipse (install the SDK?) you should be able to launch a new eclipse application that is just a copy of your current environment but this time the eclipse output will be shown in the console.

Run > Run configurations... > Eclipse Application (right click and create new) then just hit "run" using all the defaults should be ok.  But just be warned that you have to point to a new workspace and so you will have to re-import or copy your workspace projectcs, so you may not feel it is worth it.